# What is causing Arithmetic over/underflow when LINK.transferFrom() is called for ccipSend() fees?

Tags: testing, chainlink, foundry, overflow

I'm trying to write unit tests for a CCIP Sender contract.

`ccipSend()` on the `Router` is called and this line appears to be where things stop working:

`IERC20(message.feeToken).safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, onRamp, feeTokenAmount);`

Here are my test logs:

```
├─ [64128] CCIDSender::fulfill(0x5e8ebfa50e778e69264bdc847efd6c474992d0ba91772b41eb52d11737a9eafe, 1, 1658845449 [1.658e9]) 
    │   │   ├─ emit ChainlinkFulfilled(id: 0x5e8ebfa50e778e69264bdc847efd6c474992d0ba91772b41eb52d11737a9eafe)
    │   │   ├─ emit Fulfilled(_requestId: 0x5e8ebfa50e778e69264bdc847efd6c474992d0ba91772b41eb52d11737a9eafe, _revealer: REVEALER: [0x513dcA22893fBB7eB2C737A3b3D046d03D8371AD], _revealee: REVEALEE: [0x50FA752360aD481DDbE824f39Cbc32FA9FD9458d], _status: 1, _kycTimestamp: 1658845449 [1.658e9])
    │   │   ├─ [2527] Router::getFee(16015286601757825753 [1.601e19], EVM2AnyMessage { receiver: 0x000000000000000000000000c32c3d415b8597604342351d7246f85e29ad6efb, data: 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000084b59435f55534552000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, tokenAmounts: [], feeToken: 0xDB8cFf278adCCF9E9b5da745B44E754fC4EE3C76, extraArgs: 0x }) [staticcall]
    │   │   │   └─ ← 1
    │   │   ├─ [2523] LinkToken::approve(Router: [0xBb2180ebd78ce97360503434eD37fcf4a1Df61c3], 1) 
    │   │   │   ├─ emit Approval(owner: CCIDSender: [0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3], spender: Router: [0xBb2180ebd78ce97360503434eD37fcf4a1Df61c3], value: 1)
    │   │   │   └─ ← true
    │   │   ├─ [37719] Router::ccipSend(16015286601757825753 [1.601e19], EVM2AnyMessage { receiver: 0x000000000000000000000000c32c3d415b8597604342351d7246f85e29ad6efb, data: 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000084b59435f55534552000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, tokenAmounts: [], feeToken: 0xDB8cFf278adCCF9E9b5da745B44E754fC4EE3C76, extraArgs: 0x }) 
    │   │   │   ├─ [4599] MockARM::isCursed() [staticcall]
    │   │   │   │   └─ ← false
    │   │   │   ├─ [21193] EVM2EVMOnRamp::getFee(16015286601757825753 [1.601e19], EVM2AnyMessage { receiver: 0x000000000000000000000000c32c3d415b8597604342351d7246f85e29ad6efb, data: 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000084b59435f55534552000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, tokenAmounts: [], feeToken: 0xDB8cFf278adCCF9E9b5da745B44E754fC4EE3C76, extraArgs: 0x }) [staticcall]
    │   │   │   │   ├─ [5636] PriceRegistry::getTokenAndGasPrices(LinkToken: [0xDB8cFf278adCCF9E9b5da745B44E754fC4EE3C76], 16015286601757825753 [1.601e19]) [staticcall]
    │   │   │   │   │   └─ ← 10000000000000000000 [1e19], 500000000000000 [5e14]
    │   │   │   │   └─ ← 27586800000 [2.758e10]
    │   │   │   ├─ [853] LinkToken::transferFrom(CCIDSender: [0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3], EVM2EVMOnRamp: [0xDfb183BC8546E7f649292ffCa34b8DBD058DB4F7], 27586800000 [2.758e10]) 
    │   │   │   │   └─ ← "Arithmetic over/underflow"
```

Here is my test `setUp()` and relevant sections:

```
function setUp() public override {
        DeployCCIDSender deployer = new DeployCCIDSender();
        (ccidSender, helperConfig) = deployer.run();
        (routerAddress, linkAddress, oracle, jobId, oraclePayment, signUpUrl,, mockArmAddress) =
            helperConfig.activeNetworkConfig();
        router = Router(routerAddress);
        link = LinkToken(linkAddress);
        operator = Operator(oracle);

        EVM2EVMOnRampSetup.setUp();
        EVM2EVMOnRamp.FeeTokenConfigArgs[] memory feeTokenConfigArgs = new EVM2EVMOnRamp.FeeTokenConfigArgs[](1);
        feeTokenConfigArgs[0] = EVM2EVMOnRamp.FeeTokenConfigArgs({
            token: linkAddress,
            networkFeeUSDCents: 10,
            gasMultiplierWeiPerEth: 1e9,
            premiumMultiplierWeiPerEth: 1e9,
            enabled: true
        });
        EVM2EVMOnRamp onRamp = new EVM2EVMOnRamp(
            EVM2EVMOnRamp.StaticConfig({
                linkToken: linkAddress,
                chainSelector: SOURCE_CHAIN_ID,
                destChainSelector: ccidDestinationSelector,
                defaultTxGasLimit: GAS_LIMIT,
                maxNopFeesJuels: MAX_NOP_FEES_JUELS,
                prevOnRamp: address(0),
                armProxy: address(mockArmAddress)
            }),
            generateDynamicOnRampConfig(address(router), address(s_priceRegistry)),
            getTokensAndPools(s_sourceTokens, getCastedSourcePools()),
            rateLimiterConfig(),
            feeTokenConfigArgs,
            s_tokenTransferFeeConfigArgs,
            getNopsAndWeights()
        );
        onRampAddress = address(onRamp);

        Internal.TokenPriceUpdate[] memory tokenPriceUpdates = new Internal.TokenPriceUpdate[](1);
        tokenPriceUpdates[0] = Internal.TokenPriceUpdate({sourceToken: linkAddress, usdPerToken: 10000000000000000000});
        Internal.GasPriceUpdate[] memory gasPriceUpdates = new Internal.GasPriceUpdate[](1);
        gasPriceUpdates[0] =
            Internal.GasPriceUpdate({destChainSelector: ccidDestinationSelector, usdPerUnitGas: 500000000000000});
        Internal.PriceUpdates memory priceUpdates =
            Internal.PriceUpdates({tokenPriceUpdates: tokenPriceUpdates, gasPriceUpdates: gasPriceUpdates});
        IPriceRegistry(address(s_priceRegistry)).updatePrices(priceUpdates);
    }

    modifier fundLinkToRevealerAndApprove() {
        vm.startPrank(msg.sender);
        link.transfer(REVEALER, STARTING_USER_BALANCE);
        vm.deal(REVEALER, STARTING_USER_BALANCE);
        vm.stopPrank();
        vm.startPrank(REVEALER);
        link.approve(address(ccidSender), oraclePayment);
        vm.stopPrank();
        _;
    }

    modifier authorizedSenders() {
        address[] memory authorizedAddresses = new address[](1);
        authorizedAddresses[0] = REVEALER;

        vm.startPrank(0x5615dEB798BB3E4dFa0139dFa1b3D433Cc23b72f);
        operator.setAuthorizedSenders(authorizedAddresses);
        vm.stopPrank();
        _;
    }

    modifier setDestinationSelectorAndReceiverAddress() {
        vm.startPrank(anvilAccount);
        ccidSender.setCcidDestinationSelector(ccidDestinationSelector);
        ccidSender.setCcidReceiver(ccidReceiver);
        vm.stopPrank();
        _;
    }

    modifier applyRampUpdates() {
        vm.startPrank(msg.sender);
        Router.OnRamp memory newOnRamp = Router.OnRamp({
            destChainSelector: 16015286601757825753, // Sepolia
            onRamp: onRampAddress
        });
        Router.OnRamp[] memory newOnRampArray = new Router.OnRamp[](1);
        newOnRampArray[0] = newOnRamp;

        router.applyRampUpdates(newOnRampArray, new Router.OffRamp[](0), new Router.OffRamp[](0));
        vm.stopPrank();
        _;
    }

    modifier fundCcidSenderAndApproveRouter() {
        vm.startPrank(msg.sender);
        link.transfer(address(ccidSender), STARTING_USER_BALANCE);
        vm.stopPrank();
        vm.startPrank(address(ccidSender));
        link.approve(address(router), STARTING_USER_BALANCE);
        link.approve(onRampAddress, STARTING_USER_BALANCE);
        vm.stopPrank();
        _;
    }

    function testFulfillAndSend()
        public
        fundLinkToRevealerAndApprove
        authorizedSenders
        setDestinationSelectorAndReceiverAddress
        applyRampUpdates
        fundCcidSenderAndApproveRouter
    {
        vm.startPrank(REVEALER);
        ccidSender.requestStatus(REVEALEE);
        bytes32 constantRequestId = 0x5e8ebfa50e778e69264bdc847efd6c474992d0ba91772b41eb52d11737a9eafe; // ccidSender.getLatestSentRequestId();
        uint8 kycUserStatus = 1;
        uint40 nonZeroKycTimestamp = 1658845449;
        bytes memory data = abi.encode(constantRequestId, kycUserStatus, nonZeroKycTimestamp);
        operator.fulfillOracleRequest2(
            constantRequestId,
            oraclePayment,
            address(ccidSender),
            bytes4(keccak256("fulfill(bytes32,uint8,uint40)")),
            block.timestamp + 5 minutes,
            data
        );

        uint256 linkBalance = link.balanceOf(address(ccidSender));
        console.log("ccidSender balance: ", linkBalance);
        vm.stopPrank();
    }
```

These are the functions in the Sender contract being tested:

```
function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, Status _status, uint40 _kycTimestamp)
        external
        override
        recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
    {
        if (_status == Status.KYCUser) {
            if (_kycTimestamp == 0) {
                revert CCIDSender__KycTimestampShouldNotBeZeroForKycUser();
            }
        } else {
            if (_kycTimestamp != 0) {
                revert CCIDSender__KycTimestampShouldBeZeroForNonKycUser();
            }
        }

        Request storage request = _requests[_requestId];
        request.kycTimestamp = _kycTimestamp;
        request.isFulfilled = true;
        request.isHumanAndUnique = _status != Status.NotFound;
        request.isKYCUser = _status == Status.KYCUser;
        latestFulfilledRequestId[request.revealee] = _requestId;

        emit Fulfilled(_requestId, request.revealer, request.revealee, _status, _kycTimestamp);
        sendKycStatusToCcidReceiver(_status);
    }

    function sendKycStatusToCcidReceiver(Status _status) internal {
        string memory statusString = statusToString(_status);
        Client.EVM2AnyMessage memory message = Client.EVM2AnyMessage({
            receiver: abi.encode(ccidReceiver),
            data: abi.encode(statusString),
            tokenAmounts: new Client.EVMTokenAmount[](0),
            extraArgs: "",
            feeToken: link
        });

        uint64 destinationChainSelector = ccidDestinationSelector;

        uint256 fees = IRouterClient(router).getFee(destinationChainSelector, message);
        LinkTokenInterface(link).approve(address(router), fees);

        IRouterClient(router).ccipSend(destinationChainSelector, message);
    }
```

I thought the reason for the error may be because my Sender contract didn't have any LINK tokens, but I've funded it with 1000 LINK and approved spending for both the Router and onRamp. I'm also unsure if it has something to do with the `usdPerToken` and `usdPerUnitGas` in these lines of the setUp:

`tokenPriceUpdates[0] = Internal.TokenPriceUpdate({sourceToken: linkAddress, usdPerToken: 10000000000000000000});`

`gasPriceUpdates[0] = Internal.GasPriceUpdate({destChainSelector: ccidDestinationSelector, usdPerUnitGas: 500000000000000});`

Thank you for any advice that can be offered to solve this.

Comment: Can you share the actual value of the STARTING_USER_BALANCE variable if possible, please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `uint256 public constant STARTING_USER_BALANCE = 1000 ether;`
I tried setting it to 10 ether and got the same arithmetic under/overflow error
Thanks!

Comment: I removed these lines:
`uint256 fees = IRouterClient(router).getFee(destinationChainSelector, message);` and 
`LinkTokenInterface(link).approve(address(router), fees);`
from `sendKycStatusToCcidReceiver()` and added
`LinkTokenInterface(link).approve(address(router), type(uint256).max);` to the constructor. It seemed the approval in the send function was resetting the approval in the test. This isn't an ideal solution, but at least I can see a bit more of what was happening.